# Does the PostgreSQL API for PHP not support methods relating to transactions?

Tags: php, postgresql, transactions

For example with MySQLi there is an autocommit() method, a commit() and a rollback(). It appears that Postgres for PHP doesn't support methods like these and you can only do transactions in the actual SQL. is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct, and the reason is probably that the PostgreSQL C client library doesn't have such methods. It does have [`pg_transaction_status()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pg-transaction-status.php), which should make writing a transaction wrapper straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using PDO...
http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php